# window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {...}); on NuxtLink (nuxt-link) or RouterLink (router-link) click

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am going to use the simplest example to explain what I mean.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```

When the page loads for the first time the client side console logs 'page is fully loaded'. But when I click on a NuxtLink or RouterLink, I don't get a repeated log entry for the new page load.

If I use a standard link, then the console logs 'page is fully loaded' on page I visit, as it should. But it doesn't have the nice speedy page load as NuxtLink or RouterLink accomplishes.

In Rails, it has a similar feature called Turbolinks, but you can use `.on('page:load',...` to grab each page load.

Does anyone know how to fire the window-load per page load?

Answer (score 0):

The `<nuxt-link>` component is similar to the `<router-link>` component.

In HTML5 history mode, `router-link` will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page. This means that `onload` will only be triggered when the app is first loaded.

If you need to refresh and load the page every time you link to a new route, you can do this:

```js
window.location.href = 'your link'
```

By linking to the page in this way, you can find from the network panel in the browser console that every time you load a page of type `text/html` from the server.

Comment: The problem is I have a third party client-side script that runs on window load (that basically formats the DOM). Is there any way to capture the click and trigger once the new components have mounted?

Comment: Have you configured this third-party script in the `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: Yeah `plugins: ['~/plugins/scripts.client.js']`. I even tried `head: {script:[{src: '/js/scripts.client.js'}]}` hoping it would load it per page load